# How to get the source element id in endRequest Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

how do i get the id of element that caused postback in add_endRequest?
example
   //wire the End Request process,

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(requestComplete_Handler)

    //will be called after the async request completes.
    function requestComplete_Handler(sender, args)
    {
        var panel = sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id;
        switch (panel)
        {
            case "<%=upSubAccount.ClientID %>":
                __doPostBack('<%=upAllocationChart.ClientID%>');
                break;
            case "<%=upAllocationChart.ClientID%>" :   
               __doPostBack('<%=upTotal.ClientID %>');
            break;
        }
    }
```

although this works but no every time 
`sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id;`
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use the same method I suggested in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608031/how-do-i-get-the-parameter-passed-in-dopostback-in-endrequest-method/15608238#15608238).

The first argument is the event target.
This is the element that triggered the event.
However you can easily store it in a variable of your own and access it later.
You only need to replace the `__doPostBack` with your own function.

```
var orignalDoPostback = __doPostBack;
var lastEventTarget = "";
var lastEventArgument = "";
__doPostBack = function(eventTarget, eventArgument)
{
   lastEventTarget = eventTarget;
   lastEventArgument = eventArgument;
   orignalDoPostback(eventTarget, eventArgument);
}
```

Then you can use it as required.

Comment: Hi Pascal,<br> your suggested code is working perfectly i am same page, but when i navigates to different page it shows HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: This has no influence over a http response. 404 is send from the server when you navigate to a page/resource that doesn't exist. Check the link you are going to.

Comment: So whenever i have to call dopostback, i need to call __doPostBack() or originaldopostback().

Comment: Nothing changes in your code. The rest of it should remain as it is.

Comment: ok, one thing more, is it necessary to pass the second arg eventargument.

Comment: Yes, very. It tells asp.net what event to fire at the server side. If that is left blank, your request will submit, but events won't fire.

Comment: thanks very much pascal.I was passing only one argument, that was creating problem.

Comment: This will not work in case where __doPostback is fired multiple times before first request is completed. Any suggestion for that case?

Comment: To handle multiple postbacks all you need to do is not use global variables like in the example, but pass those as parameters to your own function before calling originalDoPostback